# Background server in Android

Tags: android

I need to program a Background "process" that would periodically buffer certain types of data like A, B, C. These data should be available to different Apps. For example App X receives data A and App Y receives data type B through the background.

What are my best options for designing such a server?

Is "Android Service" the way to go?

Can I have a simple C server running natively as a startup process called by init? If yes, how can I make the data available to the Dalvik Apps?

Could you provide some starting points?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to implement is a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). The place to start is with the guide topic on [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). To quote the guide: "They're the only way to share data across applications".

Comment: Thanks Ted. Just an addition: my background process gets data periodically via TCP socket. And this has to be used by Applications.

Comment: Receiving data over a TCP socket in the background is the work of a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). It sounds like you need two components: a Service to receive/update the data and a ContentProvider to make the data available to other applications.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is :

1. Create a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that will periodically get data from the socket and store it. I'm not sure how complex your data is, but I think you should yous a `SQLiteDatabase` to store it.
2. Implement a [`Content Provider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) that will expose the stored data to other applications.